# Resizing an object by entering H and W values in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to set the dimensions of an object manually by entering height and width without editing the contents of the object. Is this possible? I am able to change X and Y of an object but not W and H. Please check the attached screenshot.

[image]

Additional Info:
When I transform scale the object the following options appear where I can change the dimensions as a percentage not as the real dimensions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Properties panel doesn't have that functionality.

When you want to resize a Smart Object, do *Edit > Transform > Scale.*

Along the top of the screen you should see a control bar where you can enter the width and height numerically*. Note that if you want to rescale non-proportionally, be sure to uncheck the link icon. Remember to commit the transform by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Be careful when rescaling Smart Objects like this. If you scale up too far it will make the Smart Object look blurry (unless the Smart Object is an external vector file).

***Note:** The default units for transforming the H and W are shown as percentages, however you can type any unit you want. You are not limited to using percentages. In my example shown above, I typed 419px to change it into pixels. You can also use "in" for inches, "cm" for centimetres, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Along the top of the screen I see different options. I've edited my post to add a screenshot. Please have a look. I can change the dimensions in percentage only.

Comment: @Macit No, it's exactly the same as mine.  You can enter different units in the dimensions. You aren't limited to percentages. For example, you can simply type px after the value to specify the size in pixels, or use "in" for inches, etc, Try it.

Comment: @Macit - I've added a note to my answer for clarity.